# <input type="number"/> is not showing a number keypad on iOS

Tags: ios, html

According to [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/InputTypes.html) when I setup an input element with a type of `number` I should get a number keypad.

```
<input type="number"/>
```

> `number`:
>   A text field for specifying a number. Brings up a number pad keyboard in iOS 3.1 and later.

Looks damn near impossible to mess up.  However, when I view this simple fiddle on my iPhone or the simulator (both iOS6) the number keypad does not appear, and I get the standard alphabetic keyboard instead.

http://jsfiddle.net/Cy4aC/3/

What on earth could I possibly have messed up here?

[image]

Comment: For reference, my Android-based phone does this as well. Thank you for asking this. +1

Answer (score 176, accepted):

You need to specify the pattern:

```
<input type="number" pattern="\d*"/>
```

As a `number` can be negative or with floating point, so the <kbd>-</kbd> and <kbd>.</kbd> and <kbd>,</kbd> should be available in the keyboard, unless you specify a digits only pattern.

[image]

Comment: Yes! Thank you. The apple docs dont seem accurate then. It says about `type="number"` _"Specifying an input type of \d* or [0-9]* is equivalent to using this type."_ which doesn't seem to be true it all.  It calls it the wrong thing (type != pattern) and claims they are redundant when both are required to have the described effect... Oh Apple :(

Comment: Works on Android without pattern.  I believe the spec states that pattern is redundant (thus apples spec).

Comment: I was using JSX syntax with React and had to use two backslashes, for example: `<input type="number" pattern="\\d*" />`

Comment: This does work but looks like pattern is not supposed to be supported on number fields. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number#Pattern_validation

Comment: can confirm, W3C validator threw me an error; the input type needs to be text

Comment: Combining `type="number"` with `pattern` goes against the HTML strict rules: _Attribute pattern is only allowed when the input type is email, password, search, tel, text, or url._

Comment: @Antfish there is a solution for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51660812/best-settings-for-html-input-type-number-for-mobile-devices/51755182

Comment: 2019 update: I am testing this on an iPad mini with IOS 12, and it is most definitely not working.. I've tried various examples, codepens, etc. and none of them work. Text keyboard comes up every time.

Comment: @DanielSchmidt CSS tricks has an up-to-date article on this very issue. https://css-tricks.com/finger-friendly-numerical-inputs-with-inputmode/

Comment: @evolutionxbox thanks, but I tried their suggestion: "
..On iOS devices, using the pattern attribute with a value of [0-9]* will bring up the numeric keypad. This only works with this exact pattern — you can’t allow any extra characters.

<label for="creditcard">credit card number:</label> <input pattern="[0-9]*" type="text" name="creditcard">   " .. On an IPad mini (IOS 12), this does not work. The keyboard comes up to numbers, but you can switch it right  over to letters and the field accepts them.

Comment: Works fine but doesn't show **decimal( . )** button, Any idea what to do? In case of entering amount, **decimal** required.

Comment: How do add decimals and have it work on all browsers

Answer (score 21):

As of ios 12.2 (released March 25, 2019) this solution will work and it is the simplest to implement

```
<input type="number" inputmode="decimal"/>
```

This will bring up only the number key pad without the #+* characters that come with using input="tel"

Comment: While it passes W3C validation with a "warning", on IOS 14.4 it doesn't show an SMS code you receive on the keyboard like pattern="\d*" does. Although with pattern="\d*" you will get a W3C validation error :(

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure if this is what you want but input type = "tel" will give you the "telephone number pad".

Comment: That does work for the phone keyboard, but it also allows other craziness like `*`, `#`, `;` and `,`. I just want numbers.  And according to the docs, `type="number"` should work...

Comment: Well, what you have above in your question IS what apple call the number keypad...

Comment: _This_ is what I wanted: http://f.cl.ly/items/0P0s1b3A1S3s170F1g2Q/Screen%20Shot%202013-01-21%20at%201.55.31%20PM.png No phone stuff, just numbers.

Comment: This is great lil hack. Needed a zipcode input which is only numbers where I need the data from.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, this is very inconsistent across browsers.  iOS has gone back and forth between supporting this correctly for my use case.  I generally just want the default displayed keyboard to be the numeric one.  The last time I checked, using input type="number" correctly brings up the numeric keyboard, but the "size" attribute is ignored, which throws off my mobile format badly.  I added an attribute to all inputs that I'd prefer the numeric keyboard to use by default, and I used jQuery to change any attributes (i.e. type="number") when the browser detects as one that works correctly.  That way I don't have to go back through and update the individual inputs and allows me to only apply it in supported browsers.

It would be lovely if the major mobile O/S's would have an attribute for "default keyboard" aside from the input type.  What if a user is entering an address or zip code?  Generally those start with numbers, so showing the number keyboard by default, but allowing ANY text, is helpful.

As far as validation, I can't rely on the browser to support validation for the specific input types, so I use javascript and server-side validation.

Answer (score 1):

*Greetings. I know this question is old but I felt it's a very sought after solution and decided to post an answer.*

Here's a **solution** I've created to **address the iPad keyboard** as well as pretty much anything.

Also, this approach **does not require you to use input of type number** which in my humble opinion is very ugly.

Below, you may find a working version.

**Thoughts on Apple iPad keyboard keys...**

I had to create a keyPress event handler to capture and suppress keys on the iPad that don't seem to be handled by the keyDown event or are ambiguous???!

```js
// Bind keydown event to all input type=text in form.
$("form input[type=text]").keydown(function (e) {

// Reference to keyCodes...
var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
// Reference to shiftKey...
var shift_key = e.shiftKey;
// Reference to ctrlKey...
var ctrl_key = e.ctrlKey;
// Reference to altKey...
var alt_key = e.altKey;


// When user presses the shiftKey...
if(e.shiftKey) {

//...supress its click and whatever key follows after it.
console.log(e.shiftKey + ' and ' + key + ' supressed.');

// Deny
return false;

// ONLY Allow Numbers, Numberpad, Backspace & Tab
} else if ( (key >= 48 && key <=57) || (key >= 96 && key <=105) || (key >= 8 && key <=9) ) {

// Allow
return true;

} else {

// Deny every other key and/or shift + key combination NOT explicitly declared.
return false;
}

});


// KeyPresss to handle remaining iPAD keyboard keys!
// These keys don't seem to be handled by the keyDown event or are ambiguous???!
// Bind keypress event to all input type=text in form.
$("form input[type=text]").keypress(function (e) {

// Reference to keyCodes...
var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
// Reference to shiftKey...
var shift_key = e.shiftKey;
// Reference to ctrlKey...
var ctrl_key = e.ctrlKey;
// Reference to altKey...
var alt_key = e.altKey;

switch (key) {

// Character -> ^
case 94:
return false;

// Character -> #
case 35:
return false;

// Character -> $
case 36:
return false;

// Character -> @
case 64:
return false;

// Character -> &
case 38:
return false;

// Character -> *
case 42:
return false;

// Character -> (
case 40:
return false;

// Character -> )
case 41:
return false;

// Character -> %
case 37:
return false;

// Character -> !
case 33:
return false;

}


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="">

<label for="text1">Numbers, Numberpad, Backspace & Tab ONLY:</label>
<input id="text1" type="text" placeholder="0" min="0" input pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" value="" maxlength="4">

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading and trying a lot of ideas, none of what I found worked to show exactly the keyboard with digits only and the coma or dot.

I finished using just `<input type="number">` and a `onkeyup` handler on this input where I do something like this :

```
var previousValue = localStorage.getItem('myInputId');
if (input.getAttribute('type') === "number" && input.validity && input.validity.badInput) {
    input.value = previousValue || "";
}
localStorage.setItem('myInputId', input.value);
```

This prevents the user to write wrong characters by replacing the value with the previous one if there is a validity error (I dont't know if this is an iOS object or standard)

*beware I did't test this code snippet because I have more complex stuff around on my side but I hope you will get the idea*

With this solution :

- On iOS : the user has a full classic keyboard but opened by default on the numbers and can't write wrong characters.
- On Android, the number keyboard is perfect.
- In the future we can hope that iOS will trigger the good keyboard for numbers and that the javascript part will never be called.