# Support for input type number in iOS devices (iPad)

Tags: ios, html, ipad, input, input-type-file

i have following snippet to be used:     `<input class="myRiderbox riderfonts" data-role="none" id="pre" type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="5" value="" required>`
But, does this work on iPad and android tablet? I have tested on iOS 6 iPad simulator and mozilla. It did not work. So what is the alternative for this?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14447668/input-type-number-is-not-showing-a-number-keypad-on-ios check this...

Comment: U can accept this anaswer so ur question will have answer and i may get some reputations.

Comment: Thanks to Smitha and Shoaib.. It works well in iPad and iPhone with iOS6. But in iOS7, it allows to type Alphanumeric... How to fix it..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
      <input type="number" pattern="\d*"/>
```

Comment: That does not work on iPads with iOS 9.3.5 or older I can confirm.