# allow purely numbers in mobile browser no other thing

Tags: javascript, html, css, input

Found this did not work [Did not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14447668/input-type-number-is-not-showing-a-number-keypad-on-ios) I use `<input type="number">` for allowing only the number keyboard to show on mobile browsers, but On a mobile browser when the number keyboard shows it shows along with *+/(),. Please is it possible to hide those from showing and only allow numbers purely, no other sign purely numbers.

Comment: Post a [mcve]. Don't you think it's kinda purely silly asking a specific question that's obviously unique to your code without showing your actual code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [<input type="number"/> is not showing a number keypad on iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14447668/input-type-number-is-not-showing-a-number-keypad-on-ios). **Edit**: Check out the link, it mentions patterns which I think is what would answer this nicely.

Comment: @DanielJames <input type="number" pattern="\d*"/> did not work when i tested it on android

Comment: What version of Android are you using? Support will vary as I believe pattern is not a fully supported attribute.

Comment: @DanielJames Lolipop 5.0version is ther a cross browser version even if it is javascript to do that