# input type number not working on ipad

Tags: ipad, safari, ionic2

I am creating input in ionic which accepts only numbers. This works on all browsers and devices except for safari and ipad. i dont want the user to input anything other than numbers.I tried to do regex validation on input event but that does not stop the user from typing in alphabets. I tried keydown event but I dont get the innerText on keyDown event. please help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [<input type="number"/> is not showing a number keypad on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14447668/input-type-number-is-not-showing-a-number-keypad-on-ios)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but I happened to have the same problem, and I noticed that the what worked for me in the end hasn't been provided as an answer, so I'll add the answer for the next guy.

```
<input type="number" min="0" inputmode="numeric" pattern="[0-9]*" title="Non-negative integral number">
```

[This site](http://danielfriesen.name/blog/2013/09/19/input-type-number-and-ios-numeric-keypad/) explains the reasoning behind the solution in case you are interested.

The gist of it is that `pattern="[0-9]*"` is what triggers iOS to display a numeric keypad, while `min` and `numeric` are there to make sure that other OSes and browsers still work well with `type="number"`.

Edit: iOS 12.2 for the iPad no longer supports the `pattern="[0-9]*"` fix - perhaps use `type=tel` instead.

Comment: @ZiaUlRehmanMughal I think you'll have to update the `pattern` regex to allow floats/doubles

Comment: On iOS the numeric keypad only shows 0-9, and that specific "pattern" is the only one allowed. You cannot add "." or "," to the regex - the result is that it shows the regular full keyboard and allows any text input, even overriding checks in code to prevent that. On Android, the numeric keypad includes "." and "," by default, but only the decimal works.

Comment: works on Safari,  iPadOS 17.4 and iOS 17.3.1. Thank you!

Comment: ^ I used it without the quantifier though, just for single-digit input validation

Answer (score 4):

You can try this

```
<ion-input type="tel" inputmode="numeric" pattern="[0-9]*"></ion-input>
```

This'll force the input to be on numeric mode on iOS and the regex is just to ensure it'll get only numbers. As far as i know this won't work with `input="number"`, but this is a old solution (that still works for me). So you can try with `number` and, if it doesn't work, fall back to `tel`.

Hope this helps :D

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
<!-- HTML ->
<input type="number" onchange="allowOnlyNumbers()"/>
```

```
// js
function allowOnlyNumbers(e){
    // check input using regex
    var regex = RegExp(/[0-9]+/g);
    const test_result = regex.test(e.target.value);

    if(test_result){
      e.target.defaultValue = e.target.value;
    }else{
      e.target.value = e.target.defaultValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: iOS doesn't show the numeric keyboard for `<input type="number">`. So how did this work?

Answer (score 1):

if you can please provide a sample code of your input.
But you can try this also

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label color="primary">Inline Label</ion-label>
    <ion-input placeholder="Text Input" type="number"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
```

According to [Ionic Inputs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/input/Input/)

You can use "text", "password", "email", "number", "search", "tel", or "url". As the Input Type. Im sorry if i have mistaken your question. please try and provide a code sample. Thanks :)