# input type="number" not working for Ionic app in iOS devices

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic3, hybrid-mobile-app, numeric-keypad

In the Ionic 3 app, for numeric fields, the numeric keypad is not appearing in iOS devices. For input type `number`, the numbers are displaying in the first row of a keypad along with the alphabets. In Android, it's working fine. I tried with angular pattern `\d*` and `inputmode="numeric"` still its not working.

```
 <input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric">
```

Comment: Do you need it to be ``type="password"``?

Comment: I think you will find the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19126856/make-input-type-password-use-number-pad-on-mobile-devices. You will have to make it "text" and hide the password using CSS.

Comment: @heroin: edited the question .. need for type="number"

Comment: @Abi have you tried what is proposed in my answer here?

Comment: I tried i m still getting the number at top of the keyboard and followed by alphanumeric. still i m having the same issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [<input type="number"/> is not showing a number keypad on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14447668/input-type-number-is-not-showing-a-number-keypad-on-ios)

Answer (score 3):

I usually use

```
<ion-input type="tel" pattern="[0-9]*" style="-webkit-text-security:disc"></ion-input>
```

> -webkit-text-security:disc

to cover the input.

Comment: When i use "type" , numeric keyboard is getting launched. but my user input may contains decimal number as well...

Answer (score 1):

For those using ionic 4 and higher this is the best solution

```
<ion-input type="text" inputmode="tel"></input>
```

The key is the inputmode, that defines the keyboard that is shown. Leaving type=text allows me to allow other keys like "(" or "-" in the phone number field if needed.

See here for details: https://ionicframework.com/blog/keyboard-improvements-for-ionic-apps/

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<ion-input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*"></ion-input>
```

or

```
<ion-input type="number" pattern="\\d*"></ion-input>
```

Comment: Hi Heroin. i got numeric keypad by using the pattern="\\d*" . I need  decimal point in the keypad as well. is that possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<ion-input type="tel"></ion-input>
```