# Best settings for HTML <input type="number">, for mobile devices

Tags: mobile-safari, html-input, android-keypad, numeric-keypad, iphone-keypad

I've been reading many other questions, like these[[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25425181/iphone-ios-presenting-html-5-keyboard-for-postal-codes)[[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14447668/input-type-number-is-not-showing-a-number-keypad-on-ios)[[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14447668/input-type-number-is-not-showing-a-number-keypad-on-ios) for example, but the problem still persists.

I need to find the "cleanest" way to have a HTML `input` for mobile devices and which respects all these three rules:

1. **suitable mainly for numbers**, integer or float
2. shows **the numeric keypad on mobile devices**, on Chrome for Android and Safari for iOS, with no strange extra keys

   [image]
3. **fully respects the HTML5 rules**, tested by W3C validator

### What have I tried?

I've been across these solutions, which neither of them cumulatively respect those three above rules.

#### Solution 1

```
<input type="text" pattern="\d*" />
```

[image]

This solution despite working in iOS and fulfilling HTML rules tested by W3C validator, presents in Chrome Android the full keypad with the QWERTY keyboard.

#### Solution 2

```
<input type="number" pattern="\d*" />
```

This solution works on both systems iOS and Android Chrome, showing the number keypad on both systems, but it throws an HTML validation error with W3C validator:

> Attribute **pattern** is only allowed when the input type is email, password, search, tel, text, or url.

#### Solution 3

```
<input type="number" />
```

This solution passes the W3C HTML test, it shows nice on Chrome, but on iOS keypad it presents several unwanted keys

[image]

#### Solution 4

I see many developers using this solution

```
<input type="tel" />
```

But in Android Chrome it doesn't allow dot symbols `.` (thus no floats), and the keys have letters, which is superfluous

[image: chrome input type="tel"]

Comment: So to be clear you have a way that works on iOS and a way that works on Android, but not both? If so you can detect which OS the user is on (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21741841/detecting-ios-android-operating-system)) and then use the appropriate solution based on the OS.

Comment: @Alex the solution 2 works on both systems and that's the one I use, but it gives a HTML error on W3 validator.

Comment: hmm, well if you're set on having W3's validation I don't know of any way to make option 2 work. Is there any reason why you couldn't do the aforementioned system check?

Comment: @Alex it would be too complicated to change the inputs accordingly, since all the following jQuery functions assume a certain pattern for the inputs. I'd like to know if it's possible to get a "static" solution

Comment: Ah I see. Well then I'm sorry but I can't be of much help, sorry. Best of luck!

Comment: I can try to have always an `input type="number"` and if the system detects iOS a jQuery function that adds the pattern attribute. It's a bit cheating the validatior but it should work

Comment: Yeah, that sounds like it should work. It may be a bit of a workaround but it's the best I've got. good luck

Comment: Solution 2 seems fine but doesn't show **decimal( . )** button, Any idea what to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For your specific task I have the extraordinary solution: we take the best solution with `type="text"` and pattern and then add the JavaScript which corrects the type attribute. We do it to pass through W3 validator.

**The solution**

```js
// iOS detection from: stackoverflow.com/a/9039885 with explanation about MSStream
if(/iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent) && !window.MSStream)
{
    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="number"]');
    for(var i = inputs.length; i--;)
        inputs[i].setAttribute('pattern', '\\d*');
}
```

```html
<input type="number" />
```

My solution respects all your three rules (W3 validator inclusive).

But I have to mention that in this case(with pattern) on iOS we do not have the possibility to put float numbers with numeric keypad because on iOS we do not have any keypad with numbers including points. On Android we have this possibility. If you want to have numeric keypad with float numbers then you have to write for iOS extra solution like follows:

```html
 <input type="number" />
```

Comment: Why that passes the W3 validator if "attribute pattern is only allowed when the input type is email, password, search, tel, text, or url."? Or why not having by default `type="number"` and later on add `pattern` with code?

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira, because W3 validator does not check a JavaScript. The W3 validation is only for checking of your code. This could help you to find the mistakes in your code, but this is not a prescript. To the second question: this is the same solution - you could do it on this way too, this is a question of preference.

Comment: The `pattern="\d*"` fix seems to no longer work on the iPad (I noticed this in the Beta for iOS12.2) so we use type=tel instead.

Comment: There are [many](https://css-tricks.com/browser-detection-is-bad/), [many](https://webaim.org/blog/user-agent-string-history/), [many](http://www.mezzoblue.com/archives/2007/11/12/detect_this/), [many](https://quirksmode.org/js/support.html), [many](https://github.com/KennethanCeyer/browser-detect/issues) resources to tell you why you should never do user agent detection. One of the main reasons: you will have to keep updating your code when new browsers are introduced and existing ones become better, while browsers need to keep finding tricks to work around detection  code that isn't updated.

Answer (score 7):

There is yet another option: `<input type="text" inputmode="numeric" pattern="[0-9]*">`

[Why the GOV.UK Design System team changed the input type for numbers](https://technology.blog.gov.uk/2020/02/24/why-the-gov-uk-design-system-team-changed-the-input-type-for-numbers/) is definitely worth a read.

Note that if you still want to go the `<input type="number">` route there is a nice solution to point 4 - Scrolling - [Turn Off Number Input Spinners](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/turn-off-number-input-spinners/).

Each solution seems to have some drawbacks and I think the best fit will depend on the type of data you're trying to collect, passport number vs someone's age vs number of items.

The drawbacks to this solution that I have found are:

- the input value is now text rather than a number so you may need to do additional parsing in JS.
- on desktop browsers the input will accept alphabetical characters, the form will be invalid but you'll need to handle this and show relevant user feedback (might be automatic if using a framework)
- it's only supported by modern mobile browsers, e.g. Safari on iOS 12.2 (2019 ish) (see [spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/inputmode))

Answer (score 3):

I came across this problem and the following two solutions seem to be the best ways to answer this question

The first solution is very simple and works on both Android and IOS. This solution will have a up and down button on desktop and only a numeric keyboard on both Android and IOS;

```html
<form action="" method="">
<input pattern="[0-9]*"/>
</form>
```

The only issue with this solution is that, a user will not be able to enter , (commas) or . (periods), since they will not show up on the keyboard. If you alter the pattern, the above will no longer function on IOS.

The second solution is not supported by all browsers, however seems to work on all modern browsers including safari 15.1.

```html
<input inputmode="numeric" pattern="[0-9]*" type="text"/>
```

To see what browsers support inputmode [click here](https://caniuse.com/input-inputmode)

Good Luck

Comment: does the `pattern` support regex? If so, why not adding the dot also? Something like `[0-9.]*`

Comment: Hi João, for some reason when you add anything else to the regex, apple shows a normal keyboard. It is important to note thought that there is one difference, the difference is that if you make the regex pattern [0-9.]* IOS devices will open to the numeric and characters part of the full keyboard, which is still terrible for ux. The only other way to get the commas and periods with a full screen numeric keyboard is to use type="tel" as already suggested above. Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, because there is no straight forward way to accomplish this, the best work around is to always use an `input type="number"` with an if statement that if the device is an iOS device then the code will add the proper pattern attribute to the type.

Comment: For the sake of comprehensiveness could you add the full code?

Comment: Beware that `type=number` doesn't allow decimal point entry on an iPhone, even if `step=any` is used. (For some versions of Android or Chrome or Android keyboards the `step=any` makes the decimal point show on a phone). You can also try setting `inputmode=decimal` for Chrome - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/inputmode

Answer (score 0):

Following @Alex Charters suggestion, I propose this solution, using jQuery, which seems to be the quicker, and the more elegant.

Add this piece of code to the "onload" of the page

```js
//shows numeric keypad on iOS mobile devices
if(getMobileOperatingSystem() === "iOS"){
    $('input[type="number"]').attr("pattern", "\\d*");
}
```

The operating system detecting function is this, [taken from other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21742107/1243247):

```js
/**
 * Determine the mobile operating system.
 * This function returns one of 'iOS', 'Android', 'Windows Phone', or 'unknown'.
 *
 * @returns {String}
 */
function getMobileOperatingSystem() {
  var userAgent = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;

      // Windows Phone must come first because its UA also contains "Android"
    if (/windows phone/i.test(userAgent)) {
        return "Windows Phone";
    }

    if (/android/i.test(userAgent)) {
        return "Android";
    }

    // iOS detection from: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9039885/177710
    if (/iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(userAgent) && !window.MSStream) {
        return "iOS";
    }

    return "unknown";
}
```

I tested and it fulfils the three rules. When the operating system is iOS it adds the `pattern` attribute. I don't do it by default, because I realised that said piece of code takes some time to process according to the number of inputs, and thus it just runs when it assumes an iOS operating system.

Comment: jQuery was never quicker than pure JS. This is like C++ and Assembler languages fo example. And you have to think about  loading of the 100 kilobyte of jQuery library code and a lot of objects from jQuery in the browser memory. jQuery code is not the elegance.

Comment: And do not forget that this bounty is from you and [you cannot award a bounty to your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty). Because of all this I do not understand why you provide the same solution like from me, but you do not want to award my answer with the bounty? This is not a fair play!

Comment: @Bharata I am perfectly aware that I cannot award the bounty to myself. My problem with your approach is that you run the code always, and with this approach you just run it with iOS operating systems.

Comment: But behind this (run the code always) is very important meaning: 1. you can not know which operating system is by a client - may be it is not Android or iOS. We have a lot of this clients and may be they have the same problem like on iOS. 2. This code is small and you could save server and client resourcen for transfer additional code for checking of OS. To transfer it makes not really sense. 3. In your task a checkng of OS is not mentioned. But if you want it I can add a checking of OS to my code. Should I do it?

Comment: why do you need to add an extra class?

Comment: I do not need it, but I think is is better if you have different inputs from `type="text"` and in this case we change only a part from them, which we need. But it is not important, you could write `document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]')` instead of `document.querySelectorAll('.numeric')` if you want.

Comment: that's why I'm saying that just having `<input type="number">` and adding the `pattern="\d*"` attribute if iOS, seems to be better.

Comment: OK, if you want I can update my answer with all your wishes (checking of iOS inclusive). Should I do it?

Comment: Perfect. Thank you

Comment: But may be would you like to award my answer with the bounty now because I could in this case earn 50 points additionaly with my others answers and I would have 200 points on one day more.  It is important for me because I collect this days for the badge "Epic" and in the next two days I will be not at home.

Comment: I already set your answer as the solution. When the bounty time frame finishes, you get the bounty. You will have to wait 4 more days

Comment: I know, but the bounty time is ending tomorrow and only 1 day is grace period – this means I will get the bounty in two  days and in two days I will be not at home.

Comment: What do you want me to do? I really don't get it! I already upvoted your answer and already set it as the chosen solution. I can't do more!