# javascript: Input (type:number) value not working on mobile devices

Tags: javascript

I wrote a script to redirect to a url on button click. It works on Desktops but not Mobiles

Here is My Code

```js
 function go() {
            var day = document.getElementById("dayValue");
            var val = day.value;
            if (val != '') {
                window.location.href = '/tutorials/book/' + val;
            }else{
                alert('Please select a day!')
            }
        }
```

```html
    <input type="number" name="day" id="dayValue">
    <button type="submit" onclick="go()">Go</button>
```

On Desktop it redirects to
http://localhost:8000/tutorials/book/1

But on Mobile it shows

```
Please select a day!
```

Is there any solution with JavaScript only?

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51660812/best-settings-for-html-input-type-number-for-mobile-devices

Comment: The main problem is val is not detected on mobile devices

Comment: Your code works fine in mobile browsers too. I suspect you're running a cached page which has not all your current code.